# Dataframe calculation by row but grouping by datetime

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I'm manipulating time series data with multiple intraday lines per day. I want to be able to make decisions based on data grouped only by the day, but not as a `.groupby()`

Currently I am doing a loop on something like `np.unique(df.index.date)` then applying calculations day by day, but this is very time consuming on large data sets.

```
for day in np.unique(df.index.date):
    if df[day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")].count()[0] != 5:
        df.drop(df[df.index.date == day].index, inplace=True)
```

a snippet of data might look like :

```
Date_Time   EB
2018-09-13 9:20:00  69.45
2018-09-13 9:30:00  69.44
2018-09-13 9:40:00  69.33
2018-09-13 9:50:00  69.34
2018-09-13 10:00:00 69.36
2018-09-14 9:20:00  69.45
2018-09-14 9:30:00  69.44
2018-09-14 9:40:00  69.33
2018-09-14 9:50:00  69.34
2018-09-14 10:00:00 69.36
```

the code is iterating through each datetime day and dropping any days that does not have 5 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this without looping in Python and take advantage of C level speed by vectorizing the command.  make a series of dates, do a value count, use the value count to flag data to keep, and filter out the unwanted data.

```
# Make a series to use as a mapping for dates which should be kept
dates_with_more_than_5 = df["Date_Time"].dt.date.value_counts() > 4
# Make a column in the DataFrame which indicates which data to keep
df["keeper_data"] = df["Date_Time"].dt.date.map(dates_with_more_than_5).fillna(False)
# Filter the data and drop the keeper "flag" column
df = df[df["keeper_data"].drop(columns="keeper_data"]
```

You could do this in fewer lines, but this is pretty readable.

Edit: also, I don't see why this wouldn't be doable with a `groupby`

Comment: ```df["Date_Time"]```is not callable because this is a ```DateTimeIndex``` so i "think" it needs to be called like ```df.index.date.value_counts()``` but  ```df.index.date.``` will return a ```'numpy.ndarray'``` .

Comment: you can reset the index: `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: ah yes.. thank you so much, seeing your code has really changed the way I think about df and not using loops.

Comment: Thanks!  Glad to help.  If you didn't reset the index you can always make an `np.ndarray` into a series like this too: `pd.Series(array)` or in this case `pd.Series(df.index)`